# Python glob for Perforce file specification wildcards

Tags: python, perforce

I need to expand file specifications containing Perforce wildcards.  I need this for local files on disk (not in the Perforce depot).

That is, I need something like the standard Python `glob.glob()` that also understands the Perforce wildcard "...".  For example:

```
>>> from p4glob import p4glob        # The module I wish I had
>>> p4glob('....xml')
['a.xml', 'dir/b.xml', 'x/y/z/c.xml']
```

Does anybody have a module that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) and filter it.

```
import os

def p4glob(ext, startdir='.'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
        for f in files:
            # whatever filter params you need. e.g:
            if f.endswith(ext):
                yield os.path.join(root, f)
                # or append to an output list if you dont want a generator

# usage
[i for i in p4glob(".xml")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have the latest release of Perforce you can do this with the P4Python equivalent of `p4  status ....xml`.